# Sales Path Tree Problem DFS implementation

Tags: c#, tree, depth-first-search

Can somebody explain to me what the error in my code is? I'm trying to solve this problem as practice, and I keep getting a stack overflow error. I've been looking over it and I just can't seem to find where I'm overflowing the stack in my code. Some things to note:

- I don't actually understand in my code how the children nodes I've created in my test case "know" who their parent node is--because of this, I added those lines assigning their parents to the root node just in case. I understand this probably doesn't look very nice but I just wanted to figure out my main issue!
- I originally initialized the values of **parent** and **children** to be null when creating a new **SalesNode** object, however I was coming across **NullReferenceException**s, so I also changed this part as a safety net.

Problem:

> The car manufacturer Honda holds their distribution system in the form of a tree (not necessarily binary). The root is the company
> itself, and every node in the tree represents a car distributor that
> receives cars from the parent node and ships them to its children
> nodes. The leaf nodes are car dealerships that sell cars direct to
> consumers. In addition, every node holds an integer that is the cost
> of shipping a car to it.
>
> Take for example the tree below:
>
> ```
>               0
>           /   |   \ 
>          5    3      6
>         /    /  \    / \
>        4    2    0   1   5
>            /     /
>            1    10 
>            \
>             1
> ```
>
> A path from Honda’s factory to a car dealership, which is a path from the root to a leaf in the > tree, is called a Sales Path. The cost of a Sales Path is the sum of the costs for every node
> in the path. For example, in the tree above one Sales Path is
> 0→3→0→10, and its cost is 13 (0+3+0+10).
>
> Honda wishes to find the minimal Sales Path cost in its distribution
> tree. Given a node rootNode, write a function getCheapestCost that
> calculates the minimal Sales Path cost in the tree.
>
> Implement your function in the most efficient manner and analyze its
> time and space complexities.
>
> For example:
>
> Given the rootNode of the tree in diagram above
>
> Your function would return:
>
> 7 since it’s the minimal Sales Path cost (there are actually two Sales
> Paths in the tree whose cost is 7: 0→6→1 and 0→3→2→1→1)

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class SalesNode
{
    public int cost;
    public SalesNode[] children;
    public SalesNode parent;

    public SalesNode()
    {
        children = new SalesNode[0];
        parent = new SalesNode();
    }
}

class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SalesNode rootNode = new SalesNode();
        rootNode.children = new SalesNode[3];
        rootNode.cost = 0;
        rootNode.children[0] = new SalesNode {cost = 5};
        rootNode.children[1] = new SalesNode {cost = 3};
        rootNode.children[2] = new SalesNode {cost = 6};
        rootNode.children[0].parent = rootNode;
        rootNode.children[1].parent = rootNode;
        rootNode.children[2].parent = rootNode;
        Console.WriteLine(getCheapestCost(rootNode));
    }
    
    public static int getCheapestCost(SalesNode rootNode) {
        int minSalesPathCost = Int32.MaxValue;
        int currentPathCost = 0;
        // Create a stack to implement DFS
        Stack salesNodeStack = new Stack();
        SalesNode currentNode;
        
        salesNodeStack.Push(rootNode);
        
        while (salesNodeStack.Count > 0) { // Stack is not empty
            currentNode = (SalesNode) salesNodeStack.Pop();
            currentPathCost += currentNode.cost;
            
            if (currentNode.children.Length == 0) { // Current node is a leaf
                minSalesPathCost = Math.Min(minSalesPathCost, currentPathCost);
                do { // Keep subtracting costs until back to parent node of next unexplored path
                    currentPathCost -= currentNode.cost;
                    currentNode = currentNode.parent;
                } while (currentNode != rootNode && currentNode.children.Length == 1);
                
            } else { // Current node has children
                foreach (SalesNode child in currentNode.children) {
                    salesNodeStack.Push(child);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return minSalesPathCost;
    }
}
```

I greatly appreciate any insight. Thanks guys!

Comment: I did not follow the code (I am not writting in C#) but for shortest path you need to use BFS. For weighted shortest path you need to use Dijkstra's algorithm of A*.  Also if you get an error (for example  NullReferenceException) investigate and find the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the stack overflow is the initialisation of the `parent` field in the `SalesNode` constructor. You create a new instance of `SalesNode` by calling its constructor with `new SalesNode()`. The constructor in turn creates a new instance of the `SalesNode` in order to initialise the `parent` field, thereby calling itself. The original call to the constructor never completes, because it's stuck in a loop, trying to create an infinitely long chain of `SalesNode` instances, each of which has another `SalesNode` instance as its `parent` property, and eventually the stack is completely full of references to where control should return to if/when one of those calls to the constructor ever completes. Curiously, when I tried your code (using .net core 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019), the stack overflow exception didn't have a stack trace, so I can see why that would be difficult to debug.

The first question you should ask yourself is whether a `SalesNode` really needs to know what its parent node is. If it does, then don't instantiate the parent node in the child node's constructor, instead change the constructor's signature so that you can pass it a parent `SalesNode` which you've already instantiated. That solves the stack overflow exception.

```
public SalesNode(SalesNode parent)
{
    this.children = new SalesNode[0];
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

However, I'm not convinced that a `SalesNode` does need to know what its parent node is. It looks like the intent might be for the `salesNodeStack` to keep track of where the `getCheapestCost` method is in the tree and therefore which node to go to if it has reached a leaf node, checked whether it's the cheapest, and then needs to navigate up to the parent in order to evaluate the cost of another path. But that's not how the method is actually implemented.

The test data you're using is a tree like this

```
    0
    |
+---+---+
|   |   |
5   3   6
```

Having commented out `SalesNode`'s `parent` field and its initialisation, stepping through the code in the debugger, I see that on entering the `while (salesNodeStack.Count > 0)` loop, `currentNode` is set to the root node. OK so far.

This node has 3 children, so control goes to the `else` block, which pushes each its 3 children onto the `salesNodeStack` and then passes control back to the start of the `while (salesNodeStack.Count > 0)` loop. This time, `currentNode` is set to the last child node which was pushed onto the `salesNodeStack`, the one with cost 6, and because it doesn't have any children, `minSalesPathCost` is correctly set to 6 + 0, as this is the first leaf node to be evaluated, and therefore it's the cheapest seen so far.

The inner loop's implementation doesn't seem to match the intent described by the comment.

```
do
{ // Keep subtracting costs until back to parent node of next unexplored path
    currentPathCost -= currentNode.cost;
    //currentNode = currentNode.parent;
    currentNode = (SalesNode)salesNodeStack.Pop();
} while (currentNode != rootNode && currentNode.children.Length == 1);
```

I've commented out the reference to `currentNode.parent` because I've removed that field from the `SalesNode` class to solve the stack overflow exception, and instead tried to pop the parent node off the `salesNodeStack`, but that doesn't actually work because the next item on the stack isn't the node's parent, it's the node's previous sibling. And because the previous sibling doesn't have exactly 1 children (it has none), this loop exits. So we're back to the start of the `while (salesNodeStack.Count > 0)` loop again.

Now the first child of the root node is popped off the stack (we've completely skipped evaluating the node with cost 3) and we evaluate its cost, which comes to 5, which is correct if you ignore the fact that we've ignored the node with cost 3.

But then `currentNode = (SalesNode)salesNodeStack.Pop()` throws an InvalidOperationException because the `salesNodeStack` is now empty, so there's nothing to pop.

The two aspects of your solution that I think you need to concentrate on (other than the fact that the `SalesNode` constructor always tries to instantiate another `SalesNode`) are...

```
foreach (SalesNode child in currentNode.children)
{
    salesNodeStack.Push(child);
}
```

Rather than pushing all the (immediate) children of one node onto the stack, maybe you should be navigating to a child node, pushing that onto the stack, checking whether that child node has children and if so navigating to one of them and pushing it onto the stack, and repeat until you've reached a leaf node?

```
} while (currentNode != rootNode && currentNode.children.Length == 1);
```

The exit condition for this inner loop doesn't actually check whether we're back to a node which is a parent of a path that hasn't been visited yet (which is what `currentPathCost -= currentNode.cost` implies that it should do). Exactly what this condition should be will depend on how you implement the navigation all the way down to a leaf node before evaluating the cost of the path. You probably need to add a property/field to the `SalesNode` class to indicate whether or not it's already been visited.

#### A few other things you may want to consider...

Your test data is a tree which only has one level of child nodes. I don't think this is enough to properly test your code. The tree posted in your question would be a much better test case - try to implement this in your test data.

```
              0
              |
        +-----+-------+
        |     |       | 
        5     3       6
        |     |       |
        +   +-+-+     +-+-+
        |   |   |     |   |
        4   2   0     1   5
            |   |
            +   +
            |   |
            1  10
            |
            + 
            |
            1
```

You could change the type of `salesNodeStack` from `System.Collections.Stack` to `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<SalesNode>`. It doesn't make any functional difference, but it's type safe; it guarantees that everything in the stack is an instance of `SalesNode` and saves you having to cast each one to `SalesNode` after popping it off the stack.

You could also change the type of `SalesNode`'s children field from an array to a `System.Collections.Generic.List<SalesNode>`. Like the `Stack<T>` class, it's type safe, and unlike an array it can grow and shrink as you add items to it or remove items from it.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed and thoughtful answer! This is my 1st time asking a question on stackoverflow so I'm glad it found its way to someone who wants to be helpful. In regards to the initialization issue, that makes total sense now. As I said in my post, I had changed that in response to the null reference errors I was getting, however your tip on using the generic stack<t> type instead may fix that issue. I'm also now seeing the issue with my exit condition for my do-while loop, and I'll be taking that along with everything else to update and hopefully fix my code. Thank you sm!

Comment: @meesh You're most welcome :-) If you found this answer helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.